# Script not running unless called onclick

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This code below works when set as a fuction called onclick

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Nome_evento() {
  FB.api("/1718063768425398",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
  document.getElementById("evento").innerHTML = response.name;
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

But when

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    FB.api("/1718063768425398",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
  document.getElementById("evento").innerHTML = response.name;
      }
    });
</script>
```

It simply dont execute anything inside the script, any ideas why ? I'm really stuck at this.

Below is the full html for further context

```html
<html>
 <?php
   session_start();
   $loader = require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
 ?>
 <head>
  <title>Ember</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Using Facebook API tests space</h1>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="js/face_init_js.js"></script>
  <script>
   
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
     alert("Successfully connected to Facebook!");
      }
      else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
     alert("Login failed!");
      } else {
     alert("Unknown error!");
      }
    }); 
  </script>
  <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="Login()" />
  <input type="button" value="Evento" onclick="Nome_evento()" />
  <div id="displayName" style="padding-top: 20px">You haven't logged in yet.</div>
  <div id="userName" style="padding-top: 20px">You haven't logged in yet.</div>
  <div id="userID" style="padding-top: 20px">You haven't logged in yet.</div> 
  <div id="userEmail" style="padding-top: 20px">You haven't logged in yet.</div>
  <script>
   function Login() {
     alert("comecou login!");
     FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      // some code here
     FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        document.getElementById("displayName").innerHTML = response.name;
        document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = response.username;
        document.getElementById("userID").innerHTML = response.id;
        document.getElementById("userEmail").innerHTML = response.email;
      });
    } else {
      alert("Login attempt failed!");
    }
     }, { scope: 'email,user_photos,publish_actions' });

   }
  </script>
  <div id="evento" style="padding-top: 20px">Evento</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   FB.api("/1718063768425398",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
  document.getElementById("evento").innerHTML = response.name;
      }
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

--EDIT this is the face_init_js.js, the FB functions ( like the login) are working

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
     FB.init({
    appId: '*****************',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
     });
   };

(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

2 EDIT -

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
     FB.init({
    appId: '505610319610868',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
     });
   FB.api("/1718063768425398",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
  document.getElementById("evento").innerHTML = response.name;
      }
    });
   };
  </script>
```

Comment: Where are you loading in the Facebook js library? You cannot use it unless you load it before the code that tries to use it

Comment: Im loading the facebook js( <script src="js/face_init_js.js"></script> ), i just put the loader in a separate .js

Comment: @LeonardoMenezes, what @Patrik is asking is location of  your `<script>` tag. is it in the `<head>` (*bad*) or in just before `</body>`(*right location*)?

Comment: @RajKamal, thanks, i already solved this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use the JavaScript SDK after loading and initializing it:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    //SDK loaded, initialize it
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'your-app-id',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.5'
    });

    //now you can use FB
};
```

Links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.5
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

If that does not help you and there is no error in the browser console when you try to use FB, put a console.log at the beginning of your callback function. In other words: debug your code.

Comment: Im loading the facebook js( <script src="js/face_init_js.js"></script> ), i just put the loader in a separate .js

Comment: read the last part of my answer, just an additional information.

Comment: window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
     FB.init({
    appId: '*****',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
     });
   };

(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

Comment: Thanks for taking the time luschn. Above is the face_init_js.js code, the FB api is working just fine. I tried debugging but the only thing that i found out is that unless i define this script as a fuction, nothing inside gets executed for some reason.

Comment: @LeonardoMenezes, add code to your question, code in comments is hard to read

Comment: just as i expected. you can ONLY use the javascript sdk after FB.init.

Comment: my answer is definitely your problem. see the comment "now you can use FB"? you can only use FB.api AFTER FB.init. in your code, you are trying to use it before the javascript is initialized. it´s asynchronous.

Comment: @luschn I added in a edit the code of what i think you meant, its still not executing the script

Comment: so start debugging then, as you can read in the last part of my answer.